# what does this javascript code do?

Tags: javascript, puzzle

Found this code in our code base the other day. Not sure what it is used for. Any guesses?

```
function checkIntegerRange(x) {
  return ((x >= 0) && (x < 2020202020)) || (x == 2147483647) || (x == 4294967295);
}
```

Comment: Did you grep through to see where it's called?  I can't see why those would be special variables without context.

Comment: Well 2147483647 is the maximum value for a signed 32-bit integer and 4294967295 is the max value for an unsigned 32-bit int. Other than that I've no idea, in what context is it called/used?

Comment: I can guess at meaning of some of them, but I'm lost on 2020202020

Comment: Heres some fun trivia: It seems that 2020202020 is a Kaprekar number.  Links: http://mrob.com/pub/math/seq-kaprekar.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number

Comment: @Corey: it's binary math, obviously: `1010101010 + 1010101010 = 2020202020`

Comment: Well it in your code base and you should have more insight on it. On the face value it seems to be checking if the number entered is a signed int or unsigned int. However I didn't understand the purpose of x < 2020202020.

Comment: OMG we're all such geeks. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. - If you dont want geek answers, dont post on a geek Q/A site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2020202020 is the conversion of " " (5 spaces) to a hex string.   The author (probably one prone to writing obfuscated code :) may have wanted to ensure that a string of minimum of 5 characters converted to hex was not an considered an integer.

Here is a sample converter http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx

Comment: Uh, no, that would be 0x2020202020.  2020202020 is a decimal number

Answer (score 6):

2147483647 is the highest value that can be stored in a typical signed 32-bit integer type. 4294967295 is the analogous value for a 32-bit unsigned integer type. Possibly some other part of your code is using these as special marker values.

I have no idea what 2020202020 might signify, though it has the look of an arbitrarily chosen upper bound on something.

Answer (score 2):

What it **does** is validate that `x` is in the range 0..2020202020 **or** `x` == 2^31-1 (2147483647, the maximum positive value in a 32-bit signed integer) **or** `x` == 2^32-1 (4294967295; which would be -1 in a two's complement 32-bit signed integer value, or the highest value that can be stored in a 32-bit *unsigned* integer value).

My suspicion is that it's trying to figure out whether `x` will fit in a 32-bit integer, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it has the odd range at the beginning and why it makes the big positive exception and the -1 (or other big positive, depending) exception.

Answer (score 1):

it returns a boolean (true, false) if the number sent to it is between 0 (inclusive) and 2020202020 (non inclusive) or if the number equals 2147483647 or if it equals 4294967295.

As for the purpose... that's up to you to find out ;)

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a kind of filtering/flagging:

```
2147483647:  Hex 7FFFFFFF or bin 1111111111111111111111111111111
4294967295  Hex: FFFFFFFF or bin 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

BTW: 2*2147483647 = 4294967295-1

I would say it should check between a certain range or against some funny flags